# Setting max-file-size for multipart uploads in spring boot using Jersey-multipart

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, multipartform-data

I've tried setting this with the spring properties:
spring.http.multipart.file-size-threshold=0
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10Mb
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10Mb

...but that doesn't seem to do anything when using jersey multipart.

How can I set this max-file-size when using jersey?

EDIT: added code

application.properties

```
multipart.max-file-size=30MB
multipart.max-request-size=30MB
```

resource.java

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public TmpFileInfoDto store(
        @NotNull @Valid @FormDataParam("file") final File file,
        @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataBodyPart formDataBodyPart) throws IOException {
    // upload to S3, add DB record, etc
}
```

Comment: Which spring-boot version are you using?spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10Mb will work only for spring-boot 1.4.0 and above.For spring-boot version less than 1.4 use multipart.max-file-size=10Mb.If you are using jersey client then please share the code otherwise we could not help you

Comment: Due to an issue in Jersey I had to rewind my spring-boot version to 1.3.5.

Comment: Then use multipart.max-file-size.Post your code if it not working

Answer (score 2):

@VelNaga have anwser in the comments for me, to make easy to find this answer I am reposting the comment on the answers.

> Which spring-boot version are you
>   using?spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10Mb will work only for
>   spring-boot 1.4.0 and above.For spring-boot version less than 1.4 use
>   multipart.max-file-size=10Mb.If you are using jersey client then
>   please share the code otherwise we could not help you.

Comment: It is a comment, so I can't mark it, and also it is not my question

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping the question owner would see it.